# Journey Builder entry event configuration errors - NON SPECIFIC

Tags: journeybuilder

I've set up a journey in journey builder but am unable to test or activate it due to an error.

The error is not very specific - it just says

```
1 errors. Resolve errors in the canvas before testing or activation. Show Errors
```

Then when you click show you get:

```
Check the Entry Event for configuration issues before activating the Interaction.
```

I can't see what the problem is - I copied the entry event from a journey builder which does work, but with a different data extension as the source.

Comment: have you configured the data extension with contact builder?

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this. I ended up creating the journey from scratch.

Comment: okay, so what entry event are you using? is it date based or salesforce or contact? if you are using date based or contact then you must configure your data extension to contact builder and your DE should be sendable. You can refer this link - https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/